# Как отправить в метод foo false или true через консоль?

Tags: java

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Введите количество итерации: ");
    int num = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

    System.out.print("Введите символ: ");
    char ch = (char) reader.read();

    Solution.foo(num, ch, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитать строку и сравнить её с чем-нибудь.

Или использовать `Boolean.parseBoolean`.

Comment: у BufferedReader нету готового метода для этого?

Comment: @EzioMaciavelli, а это обязательно надо спрашивать, или может просто интерфейс в ide открыть? Понятия не имею, я вообще на джаве не пишу.

Comment: @EzioMaciavelli, `Boolean.parseBoolean`

Comment: Спасибо получилось. 

String s = reader.readLine();
        boolean b = Boolean.parseBoolean(s);

Comment: @EzioMaciavelli, можно и без лишней переменной.